# airflow BigqueryOperator is not working xcom_pull

Tags: airflow

```
Bq = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id="Bq",
    bigquery_conn_id='xxxxxxxxxxx',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    sql='aaaaaaa.sql',
    params={"project_id": project_id,
            "dataset_table_name": bq_dataset_table_name,
            "target_date": '{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="date")["date"]}}'},
)
```

If you do this, the xcom_pull will not be expanded and will be passed to SQL.
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` is not templated field. There is no need to pass xcoms with `params`. You can use it directly in `aaaaaaa.sql`.

I assume that in `aaaaaaa.sql` you are referencing with `{{ params.target_date }}`. To solve your issue replace just replace it with `{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="date")["date"] }}`

Example:

```
Bq = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id="Bq",
    bigquery_conn_id='xxxxxxxxxxx',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    sql='aaaaaaa.sql',
    params={"project_id": project_id,
            "dataset_table_name": bq_dataset_table_name,
)
```

and in `aaaaaaa.sql` :

```
SELECT *
FROM {{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="date")["date"]}}
```

Comment: thank kyou.　It's resolved.